# Equivalente a GOTO em Java

Tags: java

Bem pessoal eu gostaria de saber como faz um goto em java? ou alguma maneira de voltar a um determinado ponto do código, o pessoal diz que é perigoso usar esse tipo de comando em java... por que?

Comment: Pelo que eu saiba, na linguagem Java não há o salto incondicional, porém tem disponível em JVM bytecode, caso queira se arriscar ;-)

Comment: Normalmente mas nem sempre, GOTO é uma modelagem ruim. Djikstra (o mesmo cara do algoritmo da menor distância entre dois vértices num grafo) até escreveu um artigo: GOTO considerado perigoso (http://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não há qualquer equivalente direto ao conceito GOTO em Java<sup>[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430829/2570426)</sup>. Existem algumas opções que permitem que você faça algumas das coisas similares ao clássico GOTO. De acordo com esta [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430789/2570426), uma opção é você usar o [BREAK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html). Veja como seria:

```
search:
for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++) {
    if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
      foundIt = true;
      break search;
    }
  }
}
```