# Verificar se um elemento existe se a pagina estiver carregada. (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Estou testando um pedaço da minha aplicação, para isso criei o seguinte metodo para verificar se o elemento existe na pagina:

```
public boolean existe(){
    try{
        driver.findElement(elemento);
        return true;
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Mas tenho a necessidade de deixar um timeout do selenium configurado em 60 segundos, ou seja, a instancia aguarda até 1 minuto para encontrar o elemento, caso não encontre causa a exceção e o tratamento retorna `false`. Diante disso tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
public boolean existe(){
    if(!driver.findElements(elemento).isEmpty()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ainda sim a verificação ocorre por um minuto mesmo com a tela carregada. Estou tentando desenvolver um meio de buscar o elemento e se ele não existir naquele momento retorna falso. Dessa forma controlo o carregamento no teste e assim que carregado a pagina faz a verificação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com base na [resposta do ZeSousa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/459330/verificar-se-um-elemento-existe-se-a-pagina-estiver-carregada-selenium/459429#459429) consegui resolver o problema substituindo `wait.Until(...)` por `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elemento))` sem afetar outros timeout.

Mas achei uma solução seguindo as recomendação da [documentação do Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) para pesquisar a existencia de elemento:

> findElement não deve ser usado para procurar elementos não presentes,
> use findElements (By) e, em vez disso, afirme uma resposta de
> comprimento zero.

Já para resolver o problema do timeout utilizei um recurso baseado na [resposta do streser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/test-if-element-is-present-using-selenium-webdriver/17702728#17702728)

Código final:

```
public boolean elementoExiste(){
    // TimeOut implicito
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // Recomendação do Selenium
    Boolean existe = driver.findElements(elemento).size() > 0;
    return existe;
}
```

Obs: `Elemento` é um WebElement

Answer (score 2):

Podes configurar o timeout numa função especifica, dessa forma não estarias a afectar o comportamento geral do timeout e poderias configurar o timeout por parâmetros.
O exemplo seguinte é um extension method e foi escrito em c# mas a lógica deve manter-se em java.
Segues os seguintes passos:

1. criar um WebDriverWait com o timeout que pretenderes
2. usas o wait.until( Condiçao pretendida )
   Por vezes pode ser interessante esperar não so pelo ElementExists mas também pelo ElementIsVisible, todavia isso depende da tua aplicação.

```
public static IWebElement WaitUntilElementExists(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeout = 5)
{
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
return wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de realizar isso é usar `ExecutorService` e `Future`.

Segue exemplo de código:

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Boolean> handler = executor.submit(new Callable() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() {
                return existe();
            }
        });

        try {
            // aqui você tem 1 minuto para o handler
            System.out.println(handler.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
        } catch (TimeoutException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            handler.cancel(true);
        }
        executor.shutdownNow();
```

Caso esteja usando um java >= 8, pode diminui o código dessa maneira:

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Boolean> handler = executor.submit((Callable) () -> existe());

        try {
            // aqui você tem 1 minuto para o handler
            System.out.println(handler.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
        } catch (TimeoutException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            handler.cancel(true);
        }
        executor.shutdownNow();
```

Answer (score -5):

Opa, bem dependendo do pq espera o elemento, por ex: quando é pra da um click, eu faço um loop com o on error goto, ou ate msm pra pegar o conteudo da teg como texto ou outherHTML.

Ex:

Sub Pegar_Link_FlashScore()

Dim driver As New ChromeDriver

Dim Contador_de_erros As Integer

'_________________________________________________________________Abrir O

Chromedriver

Contador_de_erros = 0

R_tratar_1:

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

On Error GoTo tratar_1

```
Contador_de_erros = Contador_de_erros + 1

    If Contador_de_erros > 10 Then

        Application.Speech.Speak ("Erro na parte de Ligar o driver, talvez você tenha que atualizar o crome driver")

            Exit Sub

                End If
```

'<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>

```
driver.Start
```

'<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

GoTo pular_1

tratar_1:: Resume R_tratar_1

pular_1:: On Error GoTo 0

'_____________________________________________________________________________________

'__________________________________________________________________________Digitar Url

Contador_de_erros = 0

R_tratar_2:

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

On Error GoTo tratar_2

```
Contador_de_erros = Contador_de_erros + 1

    If Contador_de_erros > 10 Then

        Application.Speech.Speak ("Erro na parte de digitar o url da paginá")

            Exit Sub

                End If
```

'<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>

```
driver.Get "https://www.flashscore.com.br/"
```

'<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

GoTo pular_2

tratar_2:: Resume R_tratar_2

pular_2:: On Error GoTo 0

'_____________________________________________________________________________________

'__________________________________________________________________________Aceita Cooks

Contador_de_erros = 0

R_tratar_3:

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

On Error GoTo tratar_3

```
Contador_de_erros = Contador_de_erros + 1

    If Contador_de_erros > 10 Then

        Application.Speech.Speak ("Erro na parte de aceitar e fechar os Cooks")

            Exit Sub

                End If
```

'<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>

```
driver.FindElementById("onetrust-accept-btn-handler").Click
```

'<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

GoTo pular_3

tratar_3:: Resume R_tratar_3

pular_3:: On Error GoTo 0

'_____________________________________________________________________________________

end sub

sub AEstruturaéSimples
' vc cria uma variavel e acumula os erros gerados toda vez que vc clicka no elemento e der error

dim tratamentoDeErro as double ' por ex

tratamentoDeErro =0

' ai vc entra no loop com os erros, ao clicar e o elemento nao existir,

Contador_de_erros = 0

R_tratar_3:

On Error GoTo tratar_3

```
Contador_de_erros = Contador_de_erros + 1


    If Contador_de_erros > 10 Then ' aqui vc pode bota ´pra espera quantos erros vc quiser

        Application.Speech.Speak ("Erro na parte de aceitar e fechar os Cooks")

            Exit Sub

                End If
```

' ex; de um id de botão pra click

```
driver.FindElementById("onetrust-accept-btn-handler").Click
```

' se a estrutura der certo vc passa direto "pula"

GoTo pular_3

' se der error vc vem pro tratamento do erro, e aqui vc pode fazer oque quiser tbm,
'desde volta e tentar clickar d novo ou oque tiver em mente

tratar_3:

'porem dando error depois que vc fizer oque quiser vc deve resumir o tratamento pra poder finalizar a respota

Resume R_tratar_3

pular_3:

'e depois de tudo vc deve zerar o o tratamento de error, lembrado se vc não de o Resume , vc não conseguirar usar outra vez o tratamento de erro dentro da msm sub!

On Error GoTo 0

' ue uso essa estrutura com muita eficiencia, ela me faz ir mais rapido sem p´recisar usar application.wait

end sub

Comment: A pergunta solicita soluções em java, vide tags, não existe equivalente ao [`goto`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192760/137387) em java e se caso existisse seria dispensável e não recomendável devido a estrutura da linguagem.